click on notification in firefox on android open "about:blank"?
In my web worker I try to discribe what happen when we click on notification :
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  event.notification.close();

  const link = event.notification.data?.link || self.location.origin

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true }).then((clientList) => {
      for(const client of clientList)
        if(client.url === link && "focus" in client) return client.focus();

      try
      {
        if(clients.openWindow) return clients.openWindow(link);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error('catch', err);
      }
    })
  );
});

It works in firefox on my ubuntu, and in chrome on ubuntu AND android, but in firefox on android this open new tab "about:blank".
I don't understand why and how slove it ?

The issue you're encountering with Firefox on Android opening a new tab with about:blank instead of the expected URL when clicking on a notification likely stems from how Firefox handles clients.openWindow() in service workers. Here are several steps to debug and potentially resolve the issue:
Verify the URL
Ensure the link variable contains a valid and absolute URL. A malformed or missing URL could default to about:blank.
You can log the link variable to check its value:
console.log('Notification link:', link);

Use Absolute URLs
Firefox on Android may not handle relative URLs well in this context. Always ensure the URL is fully qualified (e.g., https://example.com).
You can normalize the URL like this:
const link = new URL(event.notification.data?.link || self.location.origin, self.location.origin).href;

Correct Error Handling
In your code, there’s a small typo in the catch block. You should log the variable error, not err:
catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in notification click handler:', error);
}

This might not be the direct cause, but it’s important to fix for accurate debugging.
Check Service Worker Scope
The service worker's scope must include the URL you're trying to open. For example, if your service worker is registered with a scope like /sw.js, ensure your target URL lies within this scope.
Register the service worker like this:
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' });

Check clients.openWindow Support
Before using clients.openWindow(), confirm it's supported in the current context. If unsupported, it may result in unexpected behavior.
if (!clients.openWindow) {
    console.error('clients.openWindow is not supported in this environment.');
}

Test in Private Mode
Sometimes extensions or cached data interfere with expected behavior. Test the functionality in a private browsing session to rule this out.
Update Firefox
Ensure you’re running the latest version of Firefox on Android. Browser updates often include bug fixes for issues like this.
Fallback for Firefox on Android
If the problem persists, detect Firefox on Android and implement a workaround:
const isFirefoxAndroid = navigator.userAgent.includes('Firefox') && navigator.userAgent.includes('Android');

if (isFirefoxAndroid) {
    console.log('Applying workaround for Firefox on Android.');
    // Implement alternate behavior here if needed
}

Final Note
If none of the above solutions work, this could be a bug specific to Firefox on Android. You might consider filing a bug report on Mozilla's Bugzilla with details about your setup and code.
